# how to remove file details from multi array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im display all the files in a div which is coming in an array `upfiles` . Using each in jquery displaying all the files with delete button, when i click on the delete button that respective file details should be deleted from an array.

Here is the jquery code each loop which im tring to delete file details from array

```
var int_loop =  1;
        var display_removebutton="";
    $(upfiles).each(function(index, file) 
        {
            if(total_size > 1000) // size limit comparision
                 display_removebutton = "<img width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' id='remove_"+int_loop+"' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />"
            size = Math.round( file.size / 1024 );
            if(size > 1000)
            {
                if(size > 1024) 
                    size_display =  Math.round(size / 1024 * 100)/100 + ' mb';
                else
                    size_display = size + ' kb';    
                alert(file.name+"("+size+")"+" will be removed atomatically from list. As it exceeds limit.");
            }
            if(size > 1024) 
                    size_display =  Math.round(size / 1024 * 100)/100 + ' mb'; // converted to mb
            else
                    size_display = size + ' kb';    
            $('#total').append("<div id='div_selec"+int_loop+"'><b>File Name :</b> "+file.name + "<b> Size:</b>" + size_display + display_removebutton + "</div>" ); 
            $("#remove_"+int_loop).click(function() {

                var curr_id = this.id;
                var id = curr_id.substr(7);
                alert(id+'file name '+file.name);
               $("#div_selec"+id).empty();
                   upfiles.splice(index, 1) //updated as the suggested in comment
//                    delete upfiles[id];
                alert(upfiles.length);

            });
             int_loop++;
    });
```

**Edited 1:**

Actually im implementing drag and drop file upload in jquery php. In validation if total size of all files is greater than 1000kb im displaying delete button, which user has to delete some of the files

**Edited 2 :**

Im getting this error in console log : `TypeError: upfiles.splice is not a function`

**Edited 3 :**

upfiles is coming from this jquery drop event:

```
$( '#total' ).bind( 'drop',function(event) {

        event.stopPropagation();    
        event.preventDefault();

        if( upfiles == 0 )
                {
                upfiles = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

                                console.log(upfiles); // in this console log it is displaying `FileList [File, File, File, File, File, File, File]` File is nothing but the files which i have dropped in a div
                }
        else {
            if(confirm( "Drop: Do you want to clear files selected already?" ) == true) {
                upfiles = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
                $( '#fileToUpload' ).val('');
            }
            else
                return;
        }
        $( "#fileToUpload" ).trigger( 'change' );
});
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle for this.

Comment: as this is the middle of the code, how can i post in fiddle. Im just displayed the part of code which i got hanged.

Comment: How come this question has so many upvotes, it's a mess?

Comment: @Nit ,because it matches Standards of Stack overflow

Comment: can any one understand what my question is? Are you guys clear?

Comment: Shouldn't the call to splice be like: `upfiles.splice(index, 1)`?

Comment: And IMO it's incorrectly marked as duplicate because the array is not modified directly within the loop but within the event handler which is typically executed much later in time.

Comment: can u please explain @jack why it is duplicate. Both the questions are different.

Comment: please see the edited 2 in the question @jasd

Comment: If `upfiles.splice` is not a function it seems that `upfiles` is not an array. Try `upfiles = Array.prototype.slice.call(upfiles, 0)` to convert an array-like object to an array. But since we don't know where `upfiles` is coming from this is just an educated guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55479/discussion-between-prassu-and-jasd).

Comment: The error wasn't there when I closed it; reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splice` is not defined because `upfiles` is of type `FileList` and the prototype of `FileList` doesn't define it. However you can *convert* any array-like object to an array using `var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLikeObject, 0)`. Now `array` has `splice` and all other array methods. See http://jsfiddle.net/8e2s7/1/ for a short example.

Comment: jasd there is an issue in deleting the files

Comment: Please raise a new question if there is a new problem. You may share the link in the chat?!

Comment: sorted the issue.. now im implementing another functionality

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .splice correctly? You have the starting index set to '0', and it is acting on files (perhaps instead of upfiles?) which would mean it would be removing the item at the start of the array.

[MDN .splice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

A jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: as this is drag and drop upload feature, how can i put this in jsfiddle. please suggest

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean? 
You just need to copy and paste the source code into a jsfiddle.