# how to reorder div ids after removing a div in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, file

**Got my own logic working fine**

Im fetching all the files which are stored in a array, and displaying in a div with id **total** , in a **total** div, im displaying all the files in individual div's with ids **div_selec**+**int_loop** in an each loop in jquery.

**this way i m displaying all the files in a div:**

```
   var int_loop =  1;
     $(upfiles).each(function(index, file) 
    {
        display_removebutton = "<img width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' class='class_remove' id='remove_"+int_loop+"' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />";
        $('#total').append("<div id='div_selec"+int_loop+"' "+style_limitexceed+"><b>File Name :</b> "+file.name + "<b> Size:</b>" + size_display + display_removebutton + "</div>" ); 
//DELETE CODE HERE AS DEFINED BELOW
    }
```

now when the user clicks on the delete icon im removing files from an array **upfiles**

HERE IS THE DELETE CODE

```
 $("#remove_"+int_loop).click(function() {
 var curr_id = this.id;
 var id = curr_id.substr(7);
 alert(index + ' this id ' + id);
 upfiles.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The problem is, if there are 3 files in div , when user delete the 1st file that is in `'div_selec"+int_loop+"'` it deletes the first file, but after deleting the first file when user tries to delete the second file: it is deleting the 3rd file instead of 2nd

because after deleting the value from an array, array is reseting the values, but in each loop ids are not reordered. So how to resolve this?

Hope you guys understand my prblem...

**edited**

**$(upfiles).each(function(index, file)** if you can see this line in code. index is not reseting, im deleting the file from an array usng this index. once the file is deleted from array, the array is reseting but index not

Comment: Using an _id_ doesn't look like the the right way to store the data you're interested in. You may find it easier to use _classes_ and or _data-* attributes_

Comment: **$(upfiles).each(function(index, file)** if you can see this line in code. index is not reseting, im deleting the file from an array usng this index. once the file is deleted from array, the array is reseting but index not

Comment: guys please help me to solve this bug

Answer (score 2):

I think when you delete value from array using splice function than all other variable shift to one level up. For Ex there is one array called fruits.

0: Banana 1: Apple 2: Grapes

Now if you delete Apple than new array will be

0: Banana 1: Grapes

So index of Grapes will be 2 to 1...
Thats why your third file is deleted...

Here is solution but not tested...I think when you delete value from array using splice function than all other variable shift to one level up. For Ex there is one array called fruits.

0: Banana 1: Apple 2: Grapes

Now if you delete Apple than new array will be

0: Banana 1: Grapes

So index of Grapes will be 2 to 1...
Thats why your third file is deleted...

Here is solution but not tested...

```
  $(upfiles).each(function(index, file) 
{
    display_removebutton = "<img class="delete_img" data-id='"+int_loop+"' width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' class='class_remove' id='remove_"+int_loop+"' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />";
    $('#total').append("<div id='div_selec"+int_loop+"' "+style_limitexceed+"><b>File Name :</b> "+file.name + "<b> Size:</b>" + size_display + display_removebutton + "</div>" ); 

}
```

I have added data-id property in img and class 'delete_img' tag above code...

```
$('body').on('click','.delete_img',function() {
 var curr_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var index_id = jQuery.inArray( curr_id, upfiles)
 upfiles.splice( index_id, 0 );
 $(this).closest('div').remove();

}
```

Here i assuming that you are using id as your array value....
So i am finding here index from value and delete the value....

Also assuming that you are not store same value twice in array...

Not tested but may be you got some point using it....

Comment: yes exactly @shail & i know that too. but how to overcome this problem

Comment: added or adding? didnt see any solution

Comment: **upfiles.splice( upfiles.indexOf( curr_id ), 1 );** what this line will do

Comment: In this line  `upfiles.indexOf( curr_id )`    first i find index from value... and than i pass this index to splice function...

Comment: i have write this with in the each loop or outside the loop?

Comment: i have written outide the loop, files are not deleting from an array

Comment: so do i have to delete my delete code which i have specified in the question

Comment: I have just replace this line `$('.delete_img').click('function() {`   with `$('body').on('click','.delete_img',function() {`

Comment: tried... it is removing files from an array but not the file which i have clicked

Comment: i think this approach is not good. if the file is deleted success, im doing some stuff with the ids like hiding divs which the files are deleted

Comment: no use.. still same problem, it is deleting from last

Comment: first of all it needs to delete the selected file but it is not deleting. it is deleting other values

Comment: First you say it delete perfect from array... Than what you have to do is just need to remove div... I have not used ID but you can still use id to delete div. In my example `var curr_id` gives you current id you can create id string and delete div by id...

Comment: ok deleting div is secondary thing.. will talk abt it later. first of all major thing is we need to remove files form an array, right now the code you have suggested, it is not working... it is not deleted the selected file also tried with 0 in upfiles.splice( upfiles.indexOf( curr_id ), 1 );

Comment: May be `upfiles.splice( upfiles.indexOf( curr_id ), 1 );` check last 1 try with 0....

Comment: Its simple code debug it line by line and go throw it once.  You are very near about to finish...

Comment: again it is just like the situation where im while posting this question. my delete code atleast deletes the file correctly for the first time, and i know what is the problem, i came here to sort that... again dont want to do r&d on another solution

Comment: **upfiles.indexOf( curr_id )** this is giving '-1' for every click on individual div

Comment: fiddle.. oops it is not possible.. as it is drag and drop upload file, im just displaying the code where im facing t=he issue

Comment: In this line `upfiles.splice( index_id, 0 );`  try 0 and 1 also. Not tested so dont know which will work...

Comment: here is the complete code which i have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176369/how-to-remove-file-details-from-multi-array

Comment: waht you getiing in `index_id`... I'm just giving clue. what you have to find is just index from value and pass it to curr_id variable... Thats it...

Comment: im getting -1 in index_id , i got you but unable to solve this, also again deleting the last records of an array instead of selected, have you seen the code which i have posted

Comment: finally got it with my own logic

Answer (score 0):

finally got my own logic and its working fine now i have taken another each loop and checking if outer file name and inner loop file name both are same then splice or else nothing